# Superfish menu customization in DNN

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke, superfish

I want to add

```
  <a href='' id="Megaanchor"> Home</a>
```

to my nav menu links ..but In Superfish as you know...all this menu thing is created by Superfish.js  file and I am unable to add this by customizing that .js script.

Just check the Superfish.js file at:

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/js/superfish.js

If you know, Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to create your own skin object to insert into a DNN skin. Your custom skin object can create the menu exactly how you want to do it.

Skin objects: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Skin-Objects.aspx
Creating a skin object: http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2008/02/20/creating-a-dotnetnuke-skinobject.aspx

Or, even easier, if you are using the DNNStandard menu, you can simply change the ULTokens.txt to incldue your extra markup.